# Python library for scripting (C++ integration)

Tags: c++, python, scripting

Please advise me good wrapper/library for python. I need to implement simple scripting in c++ app; Under "good" I mean pretty understandable, well documented, no memory leaking, fast. For creating base interface of GameObject on Python and C++; Your own experience and useful links will be nice!!! I found [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276761/exposing-a-c-api-to-python) about it, but I need more specific within gamedev context. What combinations of libraries you used for python integration into c++? For example about ogre-python it [said](http://sourceforge.net/projects/python-ogre/)

> built using Py++ and Boost.Python library

And one more question, maybe someone of you know how Python was integrated into BigWorld engine (it's own port or some library)?

Thank you!!!

Comment: SWIG, Boost, or roll-your-own. They are all well documented and any memory leaks introduced are usually your own. Another possibility: Mono with Boo or IronPython, but embedding Mono probably takes a little more effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason to avoid boost.python in game development. When you create a game, you don't just instantiate some template. You are designing it by yourself so it's of no generic design that some python library could adhere to.

Civilization IV uses boost.python, for example.

Comment: There's plenty of reasons to avoid boost.python. 1. Boost. 2. Boost. 3. Boost. It is an extremely heavy library that noticeably increases project build time. Anything that severely reduces iteration speed is harmful.

Comment: It depends on your needs. There is also a of plenty reasons not to avoid it. 1. Boost, 2. Boost, 3. Boost. It's reliable, compatible with stl, well documented, and, Boost libs usually becomes C++ standard. Not that this will become, but it tells you something about it.

Comment: I'm not saying STL is better. Most of it should also be avoided because of the same reasons. The fact that most professional game developers think so might tell you something about it.